# Не вызывается метод onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Хочу хранить состояние некоторых объектов и что бы эти объекты были доступны всюду.

Создал такой класс.

```
package com.uilmorcraft.uilmorlibrary;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v("APPLICATION", "onCreate()");
    }
}
```

В манифесте прописал так.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.uilmorcraft.uilmorlibrary">

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network " />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         ...
      </application>
</manifest>
```

По логике вещей onCreate должен вызываться хоть раз. Но ни чего не происходит. Да же ставил точку останова.

Пробовал менять манифест так

```
<application
        android:name="com.uilmorcraft.uilmorlibrary.App"
```

или так

```
<application
        android:name="App"
```

эффекта ноль.

Создал новое приложение. Сделал все то же самое и о чудо. Все работает.

Проект большой и как-то тяжко весь код переносить из старого в новый проект ради рабочего класса Application. Но думаю что да же после переноса могу получить то же самое.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Проблема может быть в `InstantRun`. Попробуйте его в настройках студии отключить

Comment: InstantRun действительно повлиял на работу класса Appllication. С чем может быть это связано? Ведь другое приложение работает нормально с InstantRun. Да и сам InstantRun дает неплохую возможность что бы не пересобирать лишний раз приложение.

Comment: Скорее всего `InstantRun` проигнорировал изменения в манифесте. В ответе расписал подробнее. Чтобы не натыкаться в будущем на другие ограничения этой функции - просто отключите её. Она не стоит того чтобы её использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstantRun` функция студии позволяет вам видеть изменения в приложении без его пересборки/перезапуска, что сокращает время разработки.

Но эта функция никогда не сможет работать во всех случаях. Например, если вы используете к-л либы, использующие кодогенерацию, типа `Realm`, `Dagger` etc изменения их использования не смогут быть отображены с помощью `InstantRun`, т.к. требуют пересборки приложения, чтобы в процессе этом сгенерировать новый код для компиляции.

Помимо упомянутых выше ограничений сам `InstantRun` далеко не идеален и может проигнорировать даже простейшие изменения. Т.е. вы можете поменять значение к-л переменной и потом часами пытаться понять почему ваш баг-фикс не исправил баг.

Таким образом все преимущества `InstantRun`-а полностью нивелируются тем, что ему нельзя доверять и его поведение непредсказуемо.

**Вывод:**

Не используйте `InstantRun`.